# "Inform xxx about the outcome" - is this phrase all right?

Tags: word-usage

"In that scenario try to auto-detect the header row. Inform page 2 about the outcome."
Is this phrase all right? What would a native English speaker use?

Comment: What is the desired meaning? Could you provide the context? As is it doesn't sound natural.

Comment: "Inform _____ about the outcome" is grammatical and sounds reasonable, but I don't understand how you inform a page about something.  Usually you would inform a person, or something that acts like one.

Comment: Idiomatically, the normal preposition in this context is [*inform him **of** the outcome*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Inform+him+of+the+outcome%22). That's about 2150 hits in Google Books, compared to just 4 for [*inform him **about** the outcome*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Inform+him+about+the+outcome%22). That's because informing someone *about* something implies giving "extended" information about the thing, not just the bare fact of the outcome / result / measurement. Metaphorically "informing" something like a ***page*** is fine in your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like software documentation from the phrases you've mentioned. If this is the case, I think the phrase you came up with it understandable but a little odd. Software terminology would be closer to "Pass the result to page 2".

As stangdon said, you usually inform some*one* about an outcome, rather than some*thing*.

Comment: You are correct, it's a comment fragment in source code. Thank you for your help.